# aufs mount fails on root partition in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mount

I have been trying to execute the following command in teminal on ubuntu.

```
sudo mount -t aufs -o br:/tmp/update/copy=rw:/=ro none /
```

copy folder contains file x but after after mount i donot see the contrnets from /tmp/update/copy in /. but the contents of / are present in /. one more thing is that when i try the following command:

```
sudo mount -t aufs -o br:/tmp/update/copy=rw none /
```

the contents still dont change. can anyone tell me a solution to this problem or a work around that would help me mount my stuff from other folder in /.
but if i try the following command it works perfectly the contents of both folders are visible

```
sudo mount -t aufs -o br:/tmp/update/copy=rw:/mnt=ro none /mnt
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this instead?

```
sudo mount -t aufs -o br=/tmp/update/copy=rw:/mnt=ro none /mnt
```

Comment: Can you explain what this command does?